# canviasjs is not showing chart multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, canvasjs

I am facing problem to show chart multiple times in a page. following is my code. my application is dynamic. but if the following can show the chart twice or more, my problem will be solved.
 This code is showing chart once.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  


</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
       text: "Using all form of color inputs",             
        fontColor: "#6A5ACD"
      },
      axisY:{
        interlacedColor: "rgb(255,250,250)",
        gridColor: "#FFBFD5"
      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "column",
        color: "darkgreen",
        dataPoints: [

        { x: 10, y: 71 },
        { x: 20, y: 55},
        { x: 30, y: 50 },
        { x: 40, y: 65 },
        { x: 50, y: 95 },
        { x: 60, y: 68 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 14}
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
  }
  </script>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"> <br> <br> <br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1",
    {
      title:{
       text: "Using all form of color inputs",             
        fontColor: "#6A5ACD"
      },
      axisY:{
        interlacedColor: "rgb(255,250,250)",
        gridColor: "#FFBFD5"
      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "column",
        color: "darkgreen",
        dataPoints: [

        { x: 10, y: 71 },
        { x: 20, y: 55},
        { x: 30, y: 50 },
        { x: 40, y: 65 },
        { x: 50, y: 95 },
        { x: 60, y: 68 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 14}
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

    chart1.render();
  }
  </script>
  <div id="chartContainer1" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle link so that we can see what should happen? Also try putting the canvasjs.js script in your head, not body.

Comment: Look at my answer below, if that was the trick, mark my answer and upvote it please.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to add them together and make sure that your first created canvas is emptied whenever the second is created:

This is the JS you need:

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title: {
        text: "Using all form of color inputs",
        fontColor: "#6A5ACD"
    },
    axisY: {
        interlacedColor: "rgb(255,250,250)",
        gridColor: "#FFBFD5"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column",
        color: "darkgreen",
        dataPoints: [

            {
                x: 10,
                y: 71
            }, {
                x: 20,
                y: 55
            }, {
                x: 30,
                y: 50
            }, {
                x: 40,
                y: 65
            }, {
                x: 50,
                y: 95
            }, {
                x: 60,
                y: 68
            }, {
                x: 70,
                y: 28
            }, {
                x: 80,
                y: 34
            }, {
                x: 90,
                y: 14
            }
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();
chart = {}; // empty your first chart


var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", {
    title: {
        text: "Using all form of color inputs",
        fontColor: "#6A5ACD"
    },
    axisY: {
        interlacedColor: "rgb(255,250,250)",
        gridColor: "#FFBFD5"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column",
        color: "darkgreen",
        dataPoints: [

            {
                x: 10,
                y: 71
            }, {
                x: 20,
                y: 55
            }, {
                x: 30,
                y: 50
            }, {
                x: 40,
                y: 65
            }, {
                x: 50,
                y: 95
            }, {
                x: 60,
                y: 68
            }, {
                x: 70,
                y: 28
            }, {
                x: 80,
                y: 34
            }, {
                x: 90,
                y: 14
            }
        ]
    }]
});
chart1.render();
chart1 = {};
```

Look at this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7td1tecs/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I have exact solution with Google Chart.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start

Regards,
Zahirul